# Own DynDNS on virtual server?

Tags: networking, server, apache2, dynamic-ip

Is there any simple way to configure say an Apache web server to handle a subdomain say mysubdomain.example.com to forward dynamic IPs? I had troubles finding a good stepwise instruction on the Internet. The goal is basically to ping mysubdomain.example.com and get back the dynamic IP i.e. 123.123.123.10 while web server still has his own IP i.e. 123.123.123.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a stepwise instruction that solves this matter:
https://www.weyand.biz/2017/07/12/dyndns-mit-plesk-ipv4-ipv6-und-php7-224.html#comment-113